# Как мне обратиться к div button__sendorder чтобы опустить его вниз при адаптиве?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть div button__sendorder , я хочу при медиа запросе опустить его вниз, не могу понять как мне к нему обратиться?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь посмотри https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У общего блока есть `flex`, так что

```css
@media(max-width: 767px){
  .discriprion_button{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```